# Django filter with reverse relation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework for API. And followed the document [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Here is a model named 'NetworkMember'.

```
class NetworkMember(CommonInfo):
    name = models.CharField('name',max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=NETWORK_STATUS_OPTS, default=None)
    network = models.ForeignKey(Network, related_name='network_members', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='sender', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='receiver', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Question is related to 'receiver' field only. So putting up below is the related 'Account' model.

```
class Account(CommonInfo):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_master_ma = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=IS_MASTER_MA_OPTS, blank=True, null=True,default=None)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE_OPTS)
    master_account = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='masterMA',on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,default=None)
    billing_account = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='BA',on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,default=None)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

One Billing account can have one master account. Again one master account can have multiple sub user accounts. So there are 2 self relations - master_account, and billing_account in the 'Account' model.

Now the network members are related to master account. 
We have some devices too. And devices are related to billing accounts. Here is device model.

```
class Device(CommonInfo):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=DEV_STATUS_OPTS, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    billing_account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='ba_devices', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    primary = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=DEV_PRIMARY_OPTS, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So I need to get devices of network members with a particular name or based on primary = 'Yes'. Lets focus on name first. 
So the flow would be -

from network member - get master account id - then get its billing account id - then get devices - then filter with the name provided.

I have managed to do this by using django filter in views.py.

```
network_accepted = NetworkMember.objects.filter(network=nid, sender=uid, status="Accepted", receiver__billing_account__ba_devices__name = 'stmk')
```

Then imported Q and tried followings too.

```
network_accepted = NetworkMember.objects.filter(Q(network=nid, sender=uid, status="Accepted")).filter(Q(receiver__billing_account__ba_devices__name = 'stmk'))

network_accepted = NetworkMember.objects.filter(Q(network=nid, sender=uid, status="Accepted") & Q(receiver__billing_account__ba_devices__name = 'stmk'))

network_accepted = NetworkMember.objects.filter(Q(network=nid, sender=uid, status="Accepted") & Q(receiver__billing_account__ba_devices__name__startswith = 'stmk'))

network_accepted = NetworkMember.objects.filter( Q(receiver__billing_account__ba_devices__name__iexact = 'stmk'))

network_accepted = NetworkMember.objects.filter( Q(receiver__billing_account__ba_devices__name__startswith = 'stmk'))
```

There is ONLY ONE device named 'stmk'. So when I do these filters, it should return only one device for that particular network member. For my testing I have hardcoded the name, but it will be dynamic. But the issue I am facing is its returning all devices for that network member if device name is found.

Ex. If I search with any other string like 'random', then there is empty result - which is fine because there are no device with that name. But if I search with  'stmk' its returning all devices. How can I restrict the device list to only 'stmk' device.  Here is 2 screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well a `Q` object is not magical, if you specify named parameters in a filter, you do the equivalent of constructing a `Q`, so the two are the same.

Comment: Is there by the way a reason why `primary` is a `CharField`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - 'Primary' will be updated to boolean. The model was created by someone else. I will be changing it soon.